# Gnuplot: setting custom labels on x2-axis

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a data files including multiple float-value columns such as following and I want to plot some columns in gnuplot.

```
1.08 1.6 4.83
1.53 2.5 5.95
2.11 3.2 6.1
2.60 4.1 7.0
```

I want to have x2-axis by following:

```
set xtics nomirror
set x2tics
set autoscale xfix
set autoscale x2fix
set ylabel 'Y_H
set xlabel 'Y_O'
set x2label 'Y_C'
p  'datafile' u 1:2 w l ls 1 t '',\
   '' u 1:(NaN):x2ticlabels(3) axes x2y1 w l ls 1 t ''
```

This way displays every single tic and It's label on the x2 axis. I would like to set custom labels for x2-axis such as 4,5,6,7 and their tics to write. How can I have custom labels and tics on x2-axis?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, is there a particular reason you use `x2ticlabels(3)` in your plot command?

Comment: No. I used x2tics(3) without any difference.

Comment: I asked because with that you will get the third column in your data file as the `x2labels`. If you don't want that then you will need to change the plot to `1:(Nan):3` and just set x2range like `set x2range[4.83:7]`

Comment: Thanks, I was the answer.

Comment: Okay I've added an answer with some explanation as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x2tics` behave the same way as `xtics` so all functions available for `xtics` are also applicable to `x2tics`.

Set a range by:

```
set x2range [1:5]
```

This command will give you a range of 1 to 5 on the x2 axis.

If you want to set custom labels then:

```
set x2tics ("one" 1, "two" 2, "three" 3, "four" 4, "five" 5)
```

This command will give you the words inside double quotes at `x2=1, x2=2` and so on.

In your case you can get numerical values on x2 axis by using `set x2range [4.83:7]` and changing second plot to `1:(NaN):3`